# How to limit input mask range with hex characters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-office, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to set input mask that allows user to enter MAC-address, which consists of hex characters: 0-9, A-F.

What I get so far is:

```
>AA\-AA\-AA\-AA\-AA\-AA
```

but this format allows to enter all alphabet characters.

The question is:

How to limit input mask range with hex characters?

Comment: An inputmask can't do this. You'll need custom code - probably using a regular expression. Search on that.

Comment: @Gustav thank you!  I thoght there is a way without VB coding, like use regexp just in the field attribute. Pity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with an Input Mask, but you can with the Validation Rule property shown below. It will let them enter whatever they want, but it won't let them save the data until it meets your rule.

```
Not Like "*[!((a-f) or (0-9))]*"
```

Comment: This rule is incomplete... one can enter less than the required string as well as incorrect strings altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this in in two parts:

1. An **input mask** of `>"#"AAAAAA;0;_`, This ensures the user can only enter # (which is prefilled in) and then six uppercase characters.
2. A **validation rule** of `Like "[#][0-9,A-F][0-9,A-F][0-9,A-F][0-9,A-F][0-9,A-F][0-9,A-F]"` which ensures the field is # then six characters which are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F.

This works very well for me and requires no VBA code.

Comment: The only part of this rule that works, is that it limits entry to 6 characters of any number and any capital letter... you can still enter G-Z - never mind the "G" at the end the answer provided.

Comment: Hi Tahwos, to be clear, the above will not stop the user entering G-Z but it does stop the record being committed to the database if a non-hex value is provided. You can then put something in the validation text to provide the user with a sensible error message. This should meet the needs of most people and poster of the original question.

Comment: Did you test this? It allows the record to be saved for me... copy/pasted directly from your edited code blocks,

Comment: just spotted some lazy copying on my part! (I have now corrected it). The "#" must be enclosed in square brackets [] this is because # means any digit unless you use the brackets. It should also be "like" rather than "not like"! Please try the amended and you should see good results.

Answer (score 1):

Failing to find an adequate solution, I read the instructions, and came up with the following;

**To limit entry to any Hexadecimal sequence preceded by "#"**. i.e #FF01A2 (pink/purple?)

**Caveat** - Be aware that Mask and Validation rules can create ambiguity between the data viewed and the data stored. The following rules store 6 characters not 7, excluding the "#" sign from the underlying data.

**Input Mask** - Automatically displays the pound sign and limits all subsequent entry to any combination of 6 numbers or letters. (The **">"** operator changes any letter that follows it to capital. Preceding the pound sign with a backslash or enclosing it in quotes, makes it a literal.)

Either `"#">AAAAAA` or `\#>AAAAAA` will work.

**Validation Rule** - Limits entry to 0-9 and a-f only. (Case is modified by the input mask above. Since the input mask above limits entry to 6 characters, use of the asterisks outside the brackets here avoids redundancy in this rule.)

`Not Like "*[!0-9A-F]*"`

**Validation Text** - Optional but recommended, to give the user some context.

`Must be in hex format: 0-9, A-F only!` (Will display in a standard message box.)

Access Table Field Properties - shown below.

[image: Access Table Design View - Field Properties]

Note: I saw a lot of examples online that included the use of "Is Null", "OR", as well as individual rules for each character - I found all of these to be a bit redundant, if they worked at all.